# rlang: Error: Can't convert a function to a string

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I created a function to convert a function name to string. Version 1 `func_to_string1` works well, but version 2 `func_to_string2` doesn't work.

```
func_to_string1 <- function(fun){
    print(rlang::as_string(rlang::enexpr(fun)))
}

func_to_string2 <- function(fun){
    is.function(fun)
    print(rlang::as_string(rlang::enexpr(fun)))
}
```

`func_to_string1` works:

```
> func_to_string1(sum)
[1] "sum"
```

`func_to_string2` doesn't work.

```
> func_to_string2(sum)
 Error: Can't convert a primitive function to a string
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

My guess is that by calling the `fun` before converting it to a string, it gets evaluated inside function and hence throw the error message. But why does this happen since I didn't do any assignments?

My questions are why does it happen and is there a better way to convert function name to string?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but I don't think it fits in a comment.

R has a mechanism called pass-by-promise,
whereby a function's formal arguments are lazy objects (promises) that only get evaluated when they are used.
Even if you didn't perform any assignment,
the call to `is.function` uses the argument,
so the promise is "replaced" by the result of evaluating it.

Nevertheless, in my opinion, this seems like an inconsistency in `rlang`*,
especially given cory's answer,
which implies that R can still find the promise object even after a given parameter has been used;
the mechanism to do so might not be part of R's public API though.

*EDIT: see coments.

Regardless, you could treat `enexpr`/`enquo`/`ensym` like `base::missing`,
in the sense that you should only use them with parameters you haven't used at all in the function's body.

Comment: This is not an inconsistency in rlang. Once a promise has been forced, it no longer has an environment, which means we can't create a quosure from it. We decided to make `enexpr()` consistent with `enquo()`.

Comment: If you don't need quasiquotation or a quosure, then using `substitute()` makes sense.

Comment: @LionelHenry I see, I guess that makes sense, although documentation could be more specific, since it does say `enexpr` corresponds to `substitute`, yet `enexpr` can return non-expressions if a given promise has already been evaluated. Also, in a quick test, `enquo` does create a quosure, though with the empty environment.

Comment: In some cases `substitute()` might also return non-expressions because the bytecode compiler unwraps constants from promises.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use this instead?

```
func_to_string2 <- function(fun){
  is.function(fun)
  deparse(substitute(fun)) 
  #print(rlang::as_string(rlang::enexpr(fun)))
}
> func_to_string2(sum)
[1] "sum"
```

Answer (score 1):

This question brings up an interesting point on lazy evaluations.

R arguments are lazily evaluated, meaning the arguments are not evaluated until its required.

This is best understood in the Advanced R book which has the following example,

```
f <- function(x) {
  10
}
f(stop("This is an error!"))
```

the result is 10, which is surprising because x is never called and hence never evaluated. We can force x to be evaluated by using `force()`

```
f <- function(x) {
  force(x)
  10
}
f(stop("This is an error!"))
```

This behaves as expected. In fact we dont even need `force()` (Although it is good to be explicit).

```
f <- function(x) {
  x
  10
}
f(stop("This is an error!"))
```

This what is happening with your call here. The function `sum` which is a symbol initially is being evaluated with no arguments when `is.function()` is being called. In fact, even this will fail.

```
func_to_string2 <- function(fun){
  fun
  print(rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(fun)))
}
```

Overall, I think its best to use `enexpr()` at the very beginning of the function.

Source:

> http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html