# Capture argument expression used for S3 dispatch

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I came across an unexpected divergence of behavior between rlang and base. Differences clearly exist, as evidenced by this quote. This was from 0.4.1, but similar language is still in 0.4.2, now referring to `enquo` instead.

> In terms of base functions, enexpr(arg) corresponds to base::substitute(arg) (though that function also features complex substitution semantics)

1. Can anyone match the behavior using rlang functions that `substitute()` has?
2. Is there a good explanation for why `enexpr()` doesn't work? I am guessing because it is related to S3 method dispatch.
3. I am specifically interested how to do this using rlang, I already can achieve the behavior I want using just base.

My example is nonsense, but what it highlights is I am unable to capture the expression (in this case a single symbol, `df`) passed in as the first argument to a generic S3 function.

```r
library(rlang)
f <- function(obj) {
  enexpr(obj)
}
print(f(print("hello")))
#> print("hello")
# behavior matches expectations

df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
class(df) <- c("custom", class(df))
`[.custom` <- function(x, i) {
call2(expr(`[`), enexpr(x), i)
}
df[4]
#> list(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)[4]
sloop::s3_dispatch(df[4])
#> => [.custom
#>  * [.data.frame
#>    [.default
#>  * [ (internal)
# It's dispatching as expected, but I don't get
# `df[4]` back as a call. 

df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
class(df) <- c("custom", class(df))
`[.custom` <- function(x, i) {
  call2(expr(`[`),substitute(x), i)
}
df[4]
#> df[4]
# substitute works

packageVersion("rlang")
#> [1] '0.4.2'
# Created on 2019-12-05 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: One of the authors of `rlang` commented on a [similar question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57500739/5793905): they preferred consistency within `rlang` instead of mimicking `base` completely.

Comment: Thanks for this comment Alexis. It makes sense, just couldn't find anywhere in the package where the inconsistencies were documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documented issue](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/303) for `rlang`, and support is likely to be added in future versions.

The current workaround is to introduce another level of quoting at dispatch:

```
`[` <- function(x, i) {
  ex <- eval_tidy( enquo(x) )
  UseMethod('[', ex)
}

`[.custom` <- function(x, i)
  call2(expr(`[`), enexpr(x), i)

df[4]
# df[4]
```